# Class Matrix Python

Tags: python, class, matrix, methods

I need help to create a class Matrix, an instance of the class, the method of transposition (transpose), finding the inverse matrix (inv) and finding the determinant of the matrix (det). Also, I need to create an Exception MatrixError that will be generated in the case the inverse matrix cannot be found.

I'm a beginner, so I'll be grateful for an explanation.

I have tried:

```
class Matrix:
   def __init__(self, n, m):
self.n = n
self.m = m
```

Comment: indentation matters in Python, so, no surprise this errors. The error message  will actually tell you indentation is why! So, fix your basic Python indentation – that might mean you have to go back to Python basics before starting to write a class!

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Answer (score 1):

It clearly errors. Why?

The error message is

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-450865340574>", line 3
    self.n = n
              ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Try and understand how you should format a code.

A fixed code should look something like

```py
class Matrix:
   def __init__(self, n, m):
    self.n = n
    self.m = m
```

And a code that completes your request is

```py
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
        self.matrix = [[0] * m for i in range(n)]

    def transpose(self):
        # here I define a new matrix with swapped dimensions
        new_matrix = [[self.matrix[j][i] for j in range(self.n)] for i in range(self.m)]
        return Matrix(self.m, self.n, new_matrix)

    def inv(self):
        # you need to implement matrix inversion using your preferred algorithm
        pass

    def det(self):
        # you need to implement matrix determinant calculation
        pass

class MatrixError(Exception):
    # try and define custom matrix error exception
    pass
```

Hope it helped. Feel free to update the thread with your progress and questions as you move along.